# Как найти второе наибольшее число , если в массиве есть 2 одинаковых?

Tags: java

Написал код для поиска второго наибольшего, но всё ломается когда ввожу что-то типо этого:{7,7,-3}. Выводит 7. В массиве без повторений всё работает нормально.

```
public static int solve(int[] arr){
        int firstHighers = Integer.MIN_VALUE, secondHighers = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for( int i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] > firstHighers){
                secondHighers = firstHighers;
                firstHighers = arr[i];
            }
            else if(arr[i] > secondHighers){
                secondHighers = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return secondHighers;
    }
```

Comment: А что, разве определено, что в этом случае нужно второе с другим значением?

Comment: @MBo Да, нужно второе наибольшее и чтобы оно не было равно наибольшему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в else-ветвь дополнительную проверку:

```
else if(arr[i] > secondHighers  && arr[i] < firstHighers){
```